# Lipschitz continuous transformation between 2 metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

**I am trying to prove that this linear transformation T is continuous and satisfy Lipschitz condition
That's my work , is it True ?**

**if it is true , can we say that T : c[a,b] to L2[a,b] is also Lipchitz continuous ? **

[image]

Comment: I see no reason to get rid of $a$, and I'd kindly ask you to rewrite you proof in MathJax|LaTeX instead of posting it as an image. I truly enjoy you handwriting, but trust me - that will be of help.

Comment: @Ilya you're right , I think I'm going to invest some time learning LaTeX to make it Suitable for the platform  , Thank you for the note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is almost right but there is a small problem. If $b <0$ you have a problem with $b^{1/2}$ so the argument fails. If you keep the constant on the right as $(b-a)^{1/2}$ then everything is fine.

(Further, $b-a \leq b$ is not correct!).

Comment: You're right.  it should be (b-a)^1/2 To stay away from the negative root .

Comment: Is it true to say that the converse transformation T : c[a,b] to L2[a,b] is also Lipchitz continuous on c[a,b] ?? I think that will be not true because we can't satisfy the Lipchitz inequality ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the converse transformation? @MomenOsama

Comment: T : c[a,b] to L2[a,b]

Comment: If you are defining $T$ by the same formula then it is Lipschitz. $(b-a)^{3/2}$ serves  as a  Lipschitz constant.  @MomenOsama

Comment: I am trying to prove that d2(Tf,Tg) <= (b-a)^(3/2) * dc(f,g)                                          Now I reached to d2(Tf,Tg) <= (b-a) * d2(f,g)

Comment: finally, I proved the inequality with the same constant (b-a)^(3/2)

Comment: I need to make sure that ...  is supremum can get into integrals ?

Comment: i.e   is   int (sup | f - g | )  = sup int (|f-g|)

Comment: What is the integral of a constant?

Comment: constant * integration

Comment: and sup is just a constant so sup int = int sup , is that true ?